# Codeigniter: Fetch customers based on a particular company id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch the customers of a particular company, where in the `company_id` is a session variable. I will post the code of my controller where in the data is being fetched. Currently all the customers are getting fetched rather than the customers of the particular company.

**CODE:**

```
public function index ()
{
if($this->input->post("export_btn")){
    $type = $this->input->post("type");
    $sel_elements = $this->input->post("selectItemsel_elements");

    // filename for download
    if("customer" == $type){
        $adco = $this->session->userdata('company_id');
        $this->db->select("naturescrm_customers.* FROM naturescrm_customers");
        $this->db->join("naturescrm_company","naturescrm_company.company_id=naturescrm_customers.company_id AND naturescrm_customers.company_id='".$adco."'","left");
        $customers = $this->customer_m->get_by("id IN (".implode(",",$sel_elements).")");
        foreach($customers as $order){
            $data[] = array(
                "customer_id" =>"".$order->customer_id,
                "first name" =>$order->name,
                "last name" =>$order->lname,
                "address 1" =>$order->address,
                "address 2" =>$order->add2,
                "city" =>$order->city,
                "state" =>$order->state,
                "country" =>$order->country,
                "zip_code" =>$order->zip_code,
                "email" =>$order->email,
                "phone" =>$order->phone,
            );
        }
}
```

Similarly in the code below, How am I supposed to pass the session variable so the customers appear based on the company session variable?

**CODE**

```
if("customer" == $type){
    $elements = array();
    $adco = $this->session->userdata('company_id');
    $customer = $this->customer_m->get();
    foreach ($customer as $v) {
        $elements[ $v->id] =  $v->customer_id .'-'.$v->name;
    }
    $this->data['elements'] = $elements;

}
```

Any help will be gratly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: add where condition after join `$this->db->Where("naturescrm_company.company_id",$adco)`

Comment: Ok, I will attempt your code. Do I remove the AND in the join in that case?

Comment: if u currently fetch all records then ,no just try only adding where condition :)

Comment: Hi, I have included the code, but all the customers are still showing. The second part of code I have written. How would I pass the session variable there?

Comment: sorry for above answerd no , yes remove ur and make join `$this->db->join("naturescrm_company","naturescrm_company.company_id = naturescrm_customers.company_id","left");`

Comment: Yes I had attempted removing that as well, but it is still the same. Have a look at the second snippet of code. How do I edit `$this->customer_m->get()` to display all customers that are affiliated with the company session variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding filter like

```
$this->db->select("naturescrm_customers.*"); 
$customer = $this->customer_m->get(); 
foreach ($customer as $v) { 
     if($adco === $v->company_id){ 
          $elements[ $v->id] = $v->customer_id .'-'.$v->name; 
     } 
}
```